# Sort users by similar interests

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables like this:

**users:**

user_id|user_name

**interests:**

user_id|interest_id|interest_name

For example 'interests' is filled like this:

```
123|1|Football
123|2|Swimming
123|3|Skiing
456|2|Swimming
...
```

Now i'm (user_id 123) logged in and i would like to know who has the most common interests like me (sorted descending).

The result should be something like this:

```
User 1: 45 interests in common (and list them)
User 2: 23 interests in common (...)
User 3: 11 interests in common (...)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

I would perhaps read my interests first into an array and then do a loop or something?

Thanks!

Comment: WHat have you tried? Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it you want the userID, count and list(interest_name)

So we just need to join interests to itslef on the interest_ID and then limit by "my Interests" (123) and use simple aggregation and a group_concat to get the list.

```
SELECT OI.User_ID
     , count(Distinct OI.Interest_ID) CommonInterestCount
     , Group_concat(OI.Interest_name) InterestList
FROM interests MyI
LEFT JOIN interests  OI
   on OI.Interest_ID = MyI.Interest_ID
WHERE MyI.user_ID = '123'
GROUP BY OI.user_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be you need a count(*) and group by

```
 select interests.user_id, interests.count(*) , users.user_name
 from  interests  
 inner join users on users.user_id = interests.user_id
 where interest_id in (select interest_id from interests where user_id = 123)
 group by interests.user_id,
```